# Force PDFs to Open in the Client from SP2013 Search

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

We have a large document library with many PDFs.  We are using search to find documents due to its ability to scale.  When regular users search and they click the link to the PDF document from the search results we want it to open by default in the browser.  This is working as required.

There is a small group of document administrators who will use the same search page, but when *they* click the link to the PDF document we want it to launch their Adobe Professional product they have installed INSTEAD of the browser.

Our solution was to ask each of the administrators to set their ‘Preferences’ on the search result page to be ‘Open in the client application’.  We have done this, but the PDF files continue to open in the browser.
Note: I do NOT want to disable the Adobe Add-on in the browser for these administrators as we only want this behavior for the SharePoint search result page and NOT a browser-wide setting.

On the system I’m using to test this out I have Adobe Reader XI installed (although the document administrators will have the Adobe Professional product) and it is the default program for .pdf files.

Is there another configuration piece I am missing for these document administrators?

**Environment**:  SharePoint Server 2013, patch level June 2015CU, WebApp Browser File Handling is set to Permissive, Client Integration is enabled on the WebApp. No Office Web Apps installed/configured.

Comment: If you _do_ disable the addin, does it open in Adobe?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm rethinking my position on NOT disabling it for the doc admins.  That may be the best solution.

Comment: Given this is behavior is controlled by the client software, it may be the best option.